# Continuity of $f(x)=\frac{x^2-9}{x+3}$

Tags: solution-verification, continuity

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2-9}{x+3}$.

> Determine the domain of $f$. Is $f$ continuous?

My answer: The domain of $f$ is $A:=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-3\}$. Yes, $f$ is continuous in $A$, but not in $\mathbb{R}$. The solution in the book says that it is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. Is this an error? Though, we can agree that the fraction can be reduced into $f(x)=x-3$, and the domain of the right-hand side is $\mathbb{R}$. But $f$ is still discontinuous at $-3$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Technically, "the domain of $f$" is ill posed. A function isn't a function unless it already has a domain. But given a function-like expression, you can figure out the _maximal set_ on which the expression makes sense. This is then also the maximal domain for a function given by that expression. This is not a criticism of you, this is a criticism of whoever authored that problem.

Comment: @Arthur I understand what you mean. The domain could be any subset of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-3\}$. Perhaps, the author wanted the reader to figure out whatever the set is that makes the function to make sense, not what the domain was the author has "thought"/"intended" it should have been.

Comment: The function can be written as $f(x)=\frac{(x+3)(x-3)}{x+3}=x-3\,.$ It obviously has a removable singularity at $x=-3$ which makes it continuous on the entire domain $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @KurtG. A removable singularity is not a point of continuity.

Comment: @L.F. That depends I guess what function we are looking at. The original $f$ or the extended function. OP seems to have a book that claims continuity in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about the original function on $\mathbb{R}$,  and on its domain it is continuous (Extended in my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.  The point $(-3, -6)$ is what's called [a removable discontinuity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html): one that can be “removed” by defining a new function

$$g(x) := \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{ if }x \in A \\ \lim_{t \to x} f(t) & \text{ if } x \notin A\end{cases}$$

where $A$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ on which $f$ is defined and continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Notice that $x^2-9=(x-3)(x+3)$ so simplifying the fraction you have $f(x)=x-3$ which is continuous. But if you don't simplify, there is a discontinuity at the value $x=-3$. So your right for claiming it isn’t in the real set.

Comment: No,  $x=-3$ is not in the domain.  Continuity is defined pointwise at each point in the domain

Comment: @Alan changed accordingly :)

Comment: The book claims it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, which is a meaningless false statement though

Comment: @Alan got confused changed again

Answer (score 0):

Continuity is defined pointwise.  That function is only defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-3\}$,  so technically it does not make sense to talk about its continuity at $x=-3$.   It is continuous at every point in its domain.

You could extend this function to a function on $\mathbb{R}$ that would be continuous by plugging the removable discontinuity that is in the other answers,  but there is no way of saying this function as is is continuous or discontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$ as that's not a possible domain